# Find multiple "switching points" by comparing the answers in columns

Tags: r

I have a data set in which subjects have made choices between A and B for 13 different B's. Below is a simplified example of what the data looks like with 54 subjects and 5 choices. (1 is A, 2 is B).

```
      subject choice1 choice2 choice3 choice4 choice5
1       1       1       1       1       2       2       
2       2       1       1       2       2       2       
3       3       1       2       1       2       2       
4       4       1       2       2       2       2
```

I would like to find the questions in which subjects switch option A to B , i.e. for subject 1 this would be choice4.

In a previous study we did this by computing number of times the subject would choose option A and then selecting the corresponding option B form a separate matrix. See code below.

However, the difference now is that instead of choosing 1 switching point, subjects were asked the questions in a randomized order, and thus there is the possibility of having multiple switching points.  For example in the table above, subject 3 switches to B at choice2 and again at choice4.

I would like to find both the first time the subject switches to option B, and the last time (before sticking with B for the rest of the choices).

```
sure_amounts <- matrix(nrow = 4, ncol = 13) # 4 treatments, 13 questions
sure_amounts[1, ] <- c(0, 2, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 8, 10)  # Option B's
sure_amounts[2, ] <- seq(2, 14, 1)
sure_amounts[3, ] <- seq(2, 14, 1)  
sure_amounts[4, ] <- seq(2, 14, 1)

b_choice <- matrix(nrow = 201, ncol = 4)
switch_choice <- matrix(nrow = 201, ncol = 4) # switching point form A to B

for(j in 1:4){    # number of treatments
  for(i in 201){   # number of subjects
    choice = NULL
    fl = data$ID == i
    k = 1 + 36*(j-1)      # 36 before going to the next treatment (due to other questions)
    
    choice = c(data[fl,k:(k+12)])
    b_choice[i,j] = length(choice[choice==1])  
    temp = b_choice[i,j]
    switch_choice[i,j] <- ifelse(temp==0, 0, sure_amounts[j, temp])
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any tips on how to approach this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how you want your expected output to look like but you can try to get data in long format and for each `subject` select rows where they switch from 1 -> 2.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -subject) %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  filter(value == 2 & lag(value) == 1 | 
         value == 1 & lead(value) == 2)

#    subject name    value
#     <int> <chr>   <int>
# 1       1 choice3     1
# 2       1 choice4     2
# 3       2 choice2     1
# 4       2 choice3     2
# 5       3 choice1     1
# 6       3 choice2     2
# 7       3 choice3     1
# 8       3 choice4     2
# 9       4 choice1     1
#10       4 choice2     2
```

Here we can see that subject 1 moves from 1 -> 2 from choice3 -> choice4 and so on.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(subject = 1:4, choice1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), choice2 = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), choice3 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), choice4 = c(2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), choice5 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

A `Base R` solution:

Essentially this code only substracts a lag of the decisions and detects if the difference is not equal to zero.

**Code:**

```
lapply(as.data.frame(t(df_1)[-1,]), function(x){
  t <- x - c(x[-1], 0) # row substracted by shortened row
  z <- which(t[-length(t)] != 0) # values not equal to zero and rm last value 
  z + 1 # remove lag
})

# $`1`
# [1] 4

# $`2`
# [1] 3

# $`3`
# [1] 2 3 4

# $`4`
# [1] 2
```

**Data:**

```
df_1 <- read.table(text = "      subject choice1 choice2 choice3 choice4 choice5
1       1       1       1       1       2       2       
2       2       1       1       2       2       2       
3       3       1       2       1       2       2       
4       4       1       2       2       2       2 ", header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)


  df %>%
  mutate(g = paste0(choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4, choice5),
         switches = as.character(map(g, ~pluck(str_locate_all(.x, "12"), 1)))) %>% 
  select(-g)
#>   subject choice1 choice2 choice3 choice4 choice5      switches
#> 1       1       1       1       1       2       2           3:4
#> 2       2       1       1       2       2       2           2:3
#> 3       3       1       2       1       2       2 c(1, 3, 2, 4)
#> 4       4       1       2       2       2       2           1:2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(subject = 1:4, choice1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), choice2 = c(1L, 
                                                                             1L, 2L, 2L), choice3 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), choice4 = c(2L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                   2L, 2L), choice5 = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                              "2", "3", "4"))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>